# Intro to JS student using isNaN (in combination to other statements) to extract string

Tags: javascript, string, extract

I suppose I will start out with baby steps...

I am a student that is trying to figure out an assignment. My instructor leaves a lot of reading between the lines on assignments. Currently we are doing string properties. Previously we were doing If/Else, while/loop, for & function statements.

For this assignment we are to prompt for a hypothetical filename (i.e. Spring2014_CS412_1.pdf) and parse it, slice it into the appropriate variables and make it alert a multitude of specifics, such as Semester:Spring, Year:2014, Class:CS412.

Problem is, this instructor doesn't seem to understand the concept of explaining the individual building blocks and how they should be added and nested together. He just throws it all in a bucket and we have to figure the pieces and how they show interact.

That said...I was hoping someone would be willing to take me under their wing and help me walk through this? I don't want the answer outright given to me, but rather help me figure out the overall structure and then help correct any granular mistakes I may overlook.

The assignment is due before Thanksgiving, so I am in a small state of panic since I have already burned several hours on this!

We are to use combinations of the following --

if/else
while loop
for loop
function
arrays

.length
.charAt
.trim
.indexOf
.substring
.toUpperCase
.toLowerCase
.lastIndexOf
.replace
isNaN

Thanks!!

Comment: [Not-A-Number](http://thecodelesscode.com/case/90).

Comment: _this instructor doesn't seem to understand the concept of explaining the individual building blocks and how they should be added and nested together._ That's the programming part. It's up to you.

Comment: ricox: parsing a pdf? How much do you know already and in doing this task, what information/assistanceguidance do you need?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a great question for Stack Exchange.  Stack Exchange is more about assisting with specific technical Q&A.  What I'd suggest is that you attempt the assignment and as you run into specific questions, post those as new questions.

Comment: @Aravind no, parsing a filename (a string.) The pdf part is irrelevant.

Comment: Mathletics: Got it, then it's fairly straight forward.

Comment: I'll give up some time to help you out. It sounds like you want to try so as long as you're trying I'll be glad to help.

Comment: @Mathletics -- Yes, but one should be given a little more than "this function does this" and "this other function/statement does this" and "this command does this"....now put them all together and build a rocketship in the next five days.

Comment: @JonathanGray--thank you much!! I have about 45 minutes until I go back to work. I know it won't all happen in a matter of minutes. But I didn't want you to think I disappeared. If I am not able to get back this evening then I will definitely be hovering the computer all weekend, off and on.

Comment: @rlcox parsing a string is not building a rocket ship. The software analogy for building a rocketship is, well, _programming a rocketship._ I understand this is hard; we've all been there. Look at each of those functions ([look them up on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) to see what they do, and figure out how it can solve ONE problem at a time, like getting the year, or getting the semester. Put the pieces together and you're done. And THAT is programming.

Comment: @Mathletics--with all due respect, I am 41 yrs old with one semester to go for a bachelors with straight A's.I understand how to research and study. Sometimes you just have trouble wrapping your head around things and just need a little guidance other than "figure it out." For someone that may do this day after day, perhaps it is that simple, but for someone that is still learning the logistics of the specific codes, let alone the do's & do-nots of how to mix them together...it isn't that simple

Answer (score 0):

Use `prompt` to get the String object (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp)

`String.split()` it on "_" (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp), for example:

```
var myString = "hello_world";
myString.split("_"); // This will return the array: ["hello", "world"]
```

I don't see where isNaN() is necessary; is there more to the assignment?

Comment: Yes...sorry for the lack of details. I was trying to keep it brief at first, just to see if anyone bit. We have been "instructed" for the lack of better terms on specific string properties and statements. We are supposed to stick with what we have been given so far.

Comment: If there's more necessary, adjust the question. If an answer helps, don't forget to accept it. :)

Comment: rlcox: Javascript is a great language. Spend time and learn it. Ask questions and then you will really understand. After all if you want to learn, you can learn, it's not about the instructor, it's about you.

Comment: @Aravind Yes JS is a great language, but unfortunately there is more to learning something than just throwing a bunch of definitions at someone and them having to figure out how each can or cannot interact with the others.

Comment: @rlcox: Learn yourself, at your own pace. What is the internet for then? :) For information, learning and discussion and progress. Of course, don't worry about assignments, they are no big deal. Learning matters.

Comment: @Aravind--I choose to worry about my grades that I am paying for. I have already spent days and hours (including collaborating with another classmate) researching the internet and I am not connecting any dots...therefor I am here asking for help. As hard as it may be for some to understand--sometimes you have to ask for some guidance. I need guidance...not explanations about how I should be able to figure this out since someone else did.